# Slow Parallelized Radix Sort

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, sorting, radix-sort

Consider this code:

```
int maxElements = numElements + minElements;
int mask = (1 << maskLen) - 1;

for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {

    if (minElements <= ((a[j] >> shift) & mask) 
        && maxElements > ((a[j] >> shift) & mask))  {

        b[sumCount[(a[j] >> shift) & mask]++] = a[j];
    }
}
```

This is the last part of the 2-bit radixSorting with threads that we have an assignment on.

The sorting works perfectly, however, it is slow as hell. I am supposed to have a speed-up (Sequential time / parallel time) of > 1, but I am hardly getting 0.5.

I can see why, at the moment I am forced to go through the whole of `a[]` to get the sorting right.

What I am wondering is if there is another way to solve this? Going through one million array places is a lot and slows down my program considerably.

Comment: radix sort usually uses a random placement of values, I don't understand why you would need a loop.

Comment: I am familiar with radix sort but I don't quite understand what you are doing here. Looping through the array of elements to sort and do what exactly with the mask?

Comment: Also this question has nothing to do with multithreading/parallel algorithms